# How to represent the paragraph content of a xml in a schema?

Tags: xml

Hi this might be a stupid question. I have a xml file like the following

```
<para>
    The int is
    <emphasis role="bold">16</emphasis>
    x 2
</para>
```

I tried to come out with a schema but not sure how to represent the "The int is x 2"

```
<xs:element name="para">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="emphasis"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="emphasis">
  ....
</xs:element>
```

Comment: the `emphasis` open and closing tags should be encoded, since they are content and not part of your xml document structure